# nlog.Docker.config doesn't override nlog.config (.NET 6)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, nlog

Things i have checked:

- nlog.Docker.config and nlog.config are at the root of the container
- 'Docker' is correctly recognized as the hosting enviroment, which means appSettings.Docker.json properly overrides appSettings.json
- All .config and .json files are copied over to the root of the container

Im initializing the logger with

```
var logger = LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Comment: You can see the logic here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/blob/master/src/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/Config/SetupBuilderExtensions.cs Maybe try to use the NLog InternalLogger to investigate what paths are being used: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: Its pretty clear now, i must set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT or DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT to Docker. The question is how is appSettings.Docker.json correctly being detected if ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is null? What is the mechanism for that

Comment: Maybe your docker-compose file is renaming your `appsettings.Docker.json` to `appsettings.json` ? Curious why you should have a `Docker`-environment, since you can use Docker-images in both Development and in Production. Notice that you can put the NLog-config in the appsettings.json file - https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json